# Help with: $\tan2θ+ 2\tanθ= 3\cotθ$ for $0\le θ\le 180$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a trigonometry question I have asked everyone I know and no one seems to be able to solve it . Any hits or steps on how to get to the answer I appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?  We can help you when you've made an effort to answer the question and you're stuck.

Comment: Is it an identity or an equation?

Comment: Bjcolby15 I did 2tanx/1-tan^2x+2tan=3cot then I tried several different methods to get the denominator the same and try making it a quadratic equation so that I would find the angles I ended up with 14^2-6x^4-1=0 I got an answer I got 15 degrees however I looked at the answer it was wrong.

Comment: @maryjames Fair enough.  Sometimes we get posters that say, "here's an equation, solve it for me" without showing anything, expecting an answer (aka "do my homework for me").  It looks like you did, but forgot to put what you've worked on - the more information you give, the better answers we can give you (and sometimes point out the mistakes - even a minus sign in the wrong place opens up the gates to a quick solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\tan 2x + 2\tan x = 3\cot x$$
$$\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x} + 2\tan x = 3\cot x$$
$$\frac{2}{1-\tan^2x} + 2 = \frac3{\tan^2 x}$$
$$2 = \frac3{\tan^2 x}-\frac{2}{1-\tan^2x} $$

Let $tan^2 x = t$ and solve

$$2 = \frac3{t}-\frac{2}{1-t} $$
$$2(t)(1-t)=3-5t$$
$$7t-2t^2-3=0$$

Comment: On the second step to the third how did you cancel the 2tanx to 2? Thank youuu! I appreciate it.

Comment: @maryjames  Divide the equation by tan x.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Set $t=\tan\theta$. Using the duplication formula for the tangent, yhe equation becomes
$$\frac{2t}{1-t^2}+2=\frac{2t(2-t^2)}{1-t^2}=\frac 3t\iff2t^2(2-t^2)=3(1-t^2)\iff 2t^4-7t^2+3=0.$$
Thus you obtain a biquadratic equation in $t$ that you can solve with the usual substitution $u=t^2$.